# Encode nested array to proper json without array indexes

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a sample 2d `$tasks` array which describes a nested structure :

```
Array
(
    [14] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 14
            [parentId] => null
            [Name] => T1
        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 40
            [parentId] => null
            [Name] => T5
        )

    [41] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 41
            [parentId] => null
            [Name] => T4
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 22
            [parentId] => 14
            [Name] => T2
        )

    [43] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 43
            [parentId] => 22
            [Name] => T2 child
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 42
            [parentId] => 14
            [Name] => T3
        )

)
```

Using the code below I'm transforming this to a proper tree structure :

```
$sortedArray = array();
// get first level
foreach($tasks as $k => $v){
    if($v['parentId'] == 'null'){
        $sortedArray[$k] = $v;
        unset($tasks[$k]);
    }
}
// sort parents
asort($sortedArray);

function getChildren(array & $a1, array & $a2){
    foreach($a1 as $k => $v){
        findChildren($v, $a2, $k);      
    }
}

function findChildren($rec1, array & $a2, $key){

    foreach($a2 as $k => $v){
        if($rec1['parentId'] == $v['Id']){
            $a2[$k]['children'][$rec1['Id']] = $rec1;
            unset($tasks[$key]);
        } else {
            if (isset($v['children'])){
                findChildren($rec1, $a2[$k]['children'], $key);
            }
        }
    }
}

findChildren($tasks, $sortedArray);
```

And tho output `$sortedArray` after running this code looks as follows :

```
Array
(
    [14] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 14
            [parentId] => null
            [Name] => T1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [22] => Array
                        (
                            [Id] => 22
                            [parentId] => 14
                            [Name] => T2
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [43] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Id] => 43
                                            [parentId] => 22
                                            [Name] => T2 child
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [42] => Array
                        (
                            [Id] => 42
                            [parentId] => 14
                            [Name] => T3
                        )

                )

        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 40
            [parentId] => null
            [Name] => T5
        )

    [41] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 41
            [parentId] => null
            [Name] => T4
        )

)
```

The problem is, that after calling json_encode on this output array in it's current state I'm getting :

```
{"14":{"Id":"14","parentId":"null"...
```

so all nested arrays are inserted with their indexes. I know I can fix the first level using `array_values`. But is there any simple way of doing this for all levels ? Without it I end up with 'children' being not an array but object which is not satisfying for me.

Comment: anyway your array elements will have some indices either initial unordered or ordered (starting from 0) and `json_encode` will convert them into JSON properties

Comment: you're sure ? using json_encode(array_values($array)) creates a javascript array of objects which is satisfying for me and the indexes are lost which is also fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code isn't present in your post, but `$tasks` was created as an associative array. In your example you also iterate through `$tasks` as you would an associative array:

```
foreach($tasks as $k => $v){
    ...
}
```

You need to add children to `$tasks` as you would with a numeric array; the difference is this:

```
//associative array
$test = array();
$test["43"] = "hello";
$test["40"] = "hello1";
$test["23"] = "hello2";
print_r($test);

//numeric array
$testb = array(); 
$testb[] = "hello";
$testb[] = "hello1";
$testb[] = "hello2";
print_r($testb);
```

Live example: http://codepad.org/tsOhX88h

With the numeric array, the top level index (e.g., 14) you've cited as the problem `{"14":{"Id":"14","parentId":"null"...` is no longer present.

As a simple final step, use this code to push the items from the associative array on to a new numeric array:

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach ($sortedArray as $key=>$val ){
    $finalArray[] = $sortedArray[$key];
}
print_r($finalArray);
```

Live example: http://codepad.org/uSGSr1DC

Or you could do it in one shot with `array_values`:

```
$finalArray = array();
$finalArray = array_values($sortedArray);
print_r($finalArray);
```

Live example: http://codepad.org/D7uBSRr8

Comment: ok, but if I won't use assoc array I won't be able to use the code I'm using now to create a tree structure out of a flat array.

Answer (score 2):

You did not include your json_encode call, if you happened to do it like this...

`json_encode(array_values($sortedArray), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`

then the force will put the numeric indexes in anyway.
Not sure if this will help you but it might help someone else who's seeing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was able to come up with something like this :

```
function makeIndexed(array & $arr, array & $par = null){
    if(is_null($par)){
        $arr = array_values($arr);
    } else {
        $par['children'] = array_values($arr);
    }

    for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {   
        $temp = @$arr[$i]['children'];
        if(isset($temp)) {
            makeIndexed($arr[$i]['children'], $arr[$i]);
        }       
    }
}
```

And now calling `makeIndexed($sortedArray);` gives me a valid JSON, where 'children' is an array of nodes and not an object. I'm aware of the fact that this code is probably ugly and lacks performance, but at least generates the proper result. If anyone can create something cleaner/shorter I'd gladly mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: Why are you using a `for` loop? You only need to use `array_values` once. `array_values` will return a numeric array that maintains all of your nested structure and removes the top level. Did you look at my example code? http://codepad.org/pIjA95rG

Comment: yes, but this doesn't work. Not sure if you've tested your case with more levels. In my case it only works for the first level.

Comment: `array_values` works with additional nested levels: http://codepad.org/D7uBSRr8 but I've also updated my answer to include a `foreach` method as well.